# refactoring jquery selector expression

Tags: jquery, selector

Is there a way that I can write the following selector in a less verbose fashion (the parent id is being repeated again and again).

```
$("#parent_id .class1 , #parent_id .class2,....")
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List your classes in the context of the object like so:

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3', $('#parent_id'))
```

**Edit**: [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bqrQC/).

Comment: +1 for js fiddle. Thanx to Matt Wolfe for an answer as well! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#parent_id").find(".class1, .class2, .class3").....
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand you
You can select multiple elements using JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

So something like $(".class1, .class2"); should work.